# Can anyone refer me to a textbook or paper that explains the $k$-space diagrams used in Fourier optics to describe diffraction?

Tags: momentum, resource-recommendations, fourier-transform, diffraction, crystals

I am taking a course in Fourier Optics. Often, we work with these $k$-space diagrams, similar to the one shown in the image below. But we use them without understanding the mathematical justification for these diagrams. I'm interested in finding a textbook or some other kind of reference that uses these diagrams extensively, and explains them. Currently, our course textbook is "Introduction to Fourier Optics" by Goodman, but that doesn't contain any such diagrams.

[image]